# camel pattern : save exchange body before WS call to enrich

Tags: routes, apache-camel

I have a camel service which:

1. expose a soap WS
2. call a REST service to get information
3. in function of the result of the step #2, do one action or an other action with the data sent on step #1

My question is how to save the data in the exchange body sent by the client on step #1 so that I get it on the step #3?

Answer (score 0):

One option is you can use MQ service to temporarily save data in the exchange body sent by the client on step #1. And use it later whenever required.

Comment: Thks but it should be complicated for my  need cause I will have to maintain these queues and do the corelation between the messages. At this time, I saved the body in a property of the exchange but I don't know if it is thé right thing to  do in this case.

Comment: That is ok if you save body in property like "abcServiceResponse" and then access in step 3  and if you want to perform two steps in parallel then create AggregationStrategy and use it you will have access to both responses in step 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using [Content Enricher](http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html) pattern with a custom AggregationStrategy. Depending how you like or need it, the AggregationStrategy can save one of the messages as a property of the merged Exchange. If not feeling like creating an AggregationStrategy code just reuse existing GroupedMessageAggregationStrategy to combine both message bodies into a List. Either way, at result you get access to both the original message and REST response.